# Email send through nodemailer In node js goes into spam in hotmail

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemailer

I've configured Nodemailer to send emails in my Node.js application, and it works fine for Gmail addresses. However, emails sent to Hotmail addresses are marked as spam.

I've ensured that my SPF and DKIM records are correctly set up. Here's a snippet of my Nodemailer code:

[image: my code]

I've tried the following:

Checked SPF and DKIM records.
Reviewed Hotmail's email delivery guidelines.
Any insights into why Hotmail might be marking these emails as spam would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

I have tried but i think its content issue while i am searching on other answers its give me same error